# Is there a convenient way to include (preferably with preview) an Asymptote drawing in a Lyx document?

Tags: graphics, lyx, asymptote

We have two great software tools, Lyx and Asymptote, which I  found very difficult to combine.
Officially, all you can do is to include in the LyX document the pdf created from the Asymptote file, while Tikz drawings can be included with Preview.
You can easily include Asymptotte drawings in Texworks, Texmaker, Overleaf, etc., but you lose the main advantage of Lyx: Seeing the documents as they would look in their final stage.
However, Asymptote compatibility seems to have a low priority for LyX developers,

The only proposal for a workaround that I could find is on a  [Russian site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064082/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-asymtote)
Unfortunately, I could not make it work.
The solution should work as follows:
**Step 1** - Add to Preamble

```
\usepackage{asymptote}
```

**Step 2** - Add some Asymptote code in an ERT,

```
\begin{asy}
label("Hello World");
\end{asy}
```

but not in the main body but in an *(activated) branch*.

**Step 3** - Compile the .asy files

```
 asy *.asy
```

which would reside in one of LyX's temporary directories (it seems that this changes).

Is any way to make this process working or is there any other alternative procedure?

Just for reference, a minimal Tex code that includes this code would look like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
label("Hello World"); 
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea about asymptote, but perhaps it would work if you used "External Material". You can read the LyX help files for more information.

Comment: Believe me that I tried and gave up. It is ridiculous to invest huge amounts of time to reverse engineer code that may change, and there are people who created it

Comment: Could you include a minimal working example of how you would include it in plain tex?